# What is the meaning of this equal after factory method in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the meaning of equal sign/operator after the factory method in this code snippet?

```dart
factory Listenable.merge(List<Listenable?> listenables) = _MergingListenable;
```

Also pointing to a proper resource about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35727#issuecomment-509306605